# how to reset wp_posts ID table in MSQL?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

is there any way to reset or auto re-arrange the ID's in wp_posts table ?

well, I have a horrible ID column which me and my friend messed with, and instead of showing posts IDs in a good way it is now showing 7 digits of numbers

knowing that I have only 60.000 posts, but now each new post shows ID p=15103222 etc...

the database became too huge with more than 300MB

and the pages in that table wp_posts are like this:
1,2,3,4,5,71,137,1314,1315,1316,1317,1318,1319,1320

So I think resetting this column (ID) in that table and re-arranging the posts IDs back from 1 to 60.000 in order, will make things better

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Delete everything in the table (or put it to temproray table) and then do

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Or put everything to temprorary table and delete this table and create it one more time.

Comment: what about the posts I have in case I deleted that table ? anyway to export all columns in that table except the ID one ? and then I will create a new table called "wp_posts" ? confused here :(

Comment: Create new table. The same as your current table. And then insert everything from current table to the new one. INSERT INTO new_table SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM current_table